# BTRFS partition's data usage is double the amount shown by DU or NCDU

Tags: btrfs

I've got a ~450gb SSD BTRFS partition. According to all the BTRFS commands 
 (such as show) and DF, it's at 410G, but according to du -chs it's at 245G.  I tried some balance commands, but it didn't work. What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have any snapshots or unmounted (sub)volumes ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. `sudo btrfs subvolume list /mc` turns up nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the output of `btrfs fi usage /`. Especially note what's indicated on the `Device allocated:` and `Used:` lines.

Because btrfs uses a two-stage allocator, it first allocates disk space into block groups (such as DATA), and then allocates extents within them for actual file data. After some use, it's possible to end up with a lot of data allocated but not used - by itself this is not a problem, but can be fixed with a balance (which would reclaim the unused space to be used for other block groups, such as METADATA).

Also, since you mentioned ncdu, you may want to check out [btdu](https://github.com/CyberShadow/btdu), an ncdu-like tool I made for btrfs. It may help you better visualize what disk space is being used for.

Comment: Wow, that btdu is amazing! Thank you!